# Generate ranges from sequences based on missing values

Tags: python, python-3.x

Given a range, `range(101)`, I have known missing inputs from the sequence,

```
{ 8, 23, 56 }
```

In this range, the only significant numbers are the start and end, `0` and `100`.  Here's what my initialization looks like:

```
r = tuple(range(101))
init_start, init_end = r[0], r[-1]

missing = { 8, 23, 56 }
r = tuple(filter(lambda n: n not in missing, r))
```

Now here is where I get stuck.  I don't know how to approach generating the sub-ranges where the holes are.  The expected output here is `0, 7`, `9, 22`, `24, 55`, and `57, 100`.  I could brute force it with the known missing values, but then it doesn't handle edge cases (what if I only have one value in the range?).

## Edit

Someone posted a working solution for the "happy path" of the problem, but it misses edge cases:

- how to handle sequentially missing values?
- what if the start or end are in the missing values?

---

```
r = tuple(range(101))
init_start, init_end = r[0], r[-1]

missing = [8, 23, 56]
r = tuple(filter(lambda n: n not in missing, r))

def gen_ranges():
    start = init_start
    end = 0

    for n in sorted(missing):
        yield start
        start = n + 1

        end = n - 1
        yield end

    yield start
    yield init_end

>>> list(gen_ranges())
[0, 7, 9, 22, 24, 55, 57, 100]
```

Comment: Not quite clear what's the input and what's part of your attempt.

Comment: @HeapOverflow The input is the start, end of a range (`Tuple`), and what values from that range are missing as a `List`.  The `todo` is generating sub-ranges around the missing values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution using `itertools.groupby()`:

```
holes = {8, 23, 56}

from itertools import groupby

def generate(holes, r=range(0, 101)):
    for v, g in groupby(r, lambda k: k in holes):
        if v is False:
            l = [*g]
            yield from (l[0], l[-1])

print(list(generate(holes)))
```

Prints:

```
[0, 7, 9, 22, 24, 55, 57, 100]
```

---

Other inputs:

```
holes = {8, 10, 56}  # [0, 7, 9, 9, 11, 55, 57, 100]
holes = {8, 9, 56}   # [0, 7, 10, 55, 57, 100]
```

---

EDIT (some explanation):

With [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) I'm making groups from the `range()` generator using the `key` function. Here is the key function `k in holes` (`k` is value from the `range()`). If the value returned from the key function changes, that means one consecutive group. I basically do this:

```
False [0, 1, 2, ... 5, 6, 7]  # group 1 (Take first, last)
True [8, 9]                   # group 2
False [10, 11, ... 54, 55]    # group 3 (Take first, last)
True [56]                     # group 4
False [57, 58, ... 99, 100]   # group 5 (Take first, last)
```

Comment: Could you explain your logic there?  It looks like it ticks all the boxes but I'm unfamiliar with `groupby` (or `yield from`)

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 I added some explanation to my answer.

Comment: Very nice on all fronts.  Even handles the edge case if everything is missing.  Thank you very much

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 Yes, that's why I like `itertools` :) It most cases it handles edge cases well (though sometimes not) - it's good to know them

Answer (score 3):

I see a couple of issues:

1. You need to ensure the values in `missing` are sorted;
2. You're not outputting the last pair of values after you finish processing the values in `missing`

This should give the results you want (note I've added `missing` as a parameter to ease testing):

```
def gen_ranges(missing):
    start = init_start
    end = 0

    for n in sorted(missing):
        if n == start:
            start = n + 1
            continue
        yield start
        start = n + 1

        end = n - 1
        yield end

    if start <= init_end:
        yield start
        yield init_end

print(list(gen_ranges({ 8,  9, 56 })))
print(list(gen_ranges({ 0 })))
print(list(gen_ranges({ 100 })))
print(list(gen_ranges({ 0, 100 })))
print(list(gen_ranges({ 1, 100 })))
print(list(gen_ranges({ 0, 99 })))
print(list(gen_ranges({ 0, 50, 100 })))
print(list(gen_ranges({ 0, 1, 50, 99, 100 })))
```

Output:

```
[0, 7, 10, 55, 57, 100]
[1, 100]
[0, 99]
[1, 99]
[0, 0, 2, 99]
[1, 98, 100, 100]
[1, 49, 51, 99]
[2, 49, 51, 98]
```

Comment: I didn't realize `Set` wasn't ordered in python; interesting.  The data I'm actually working with comes through as a `List`, so I'll keep the sorted note in mind.  How should I address the edge cases where the start / end may be the missing pieces?

Comment: Doesn't seem to work with `missing = { 8, 9, 56 }` or `missing = { 8, 10, 56 }`.

Comment: @RickHitchcock Yeah, in that scenario it should generate `9, 9`

Comment: It does generate `9, 9` for `{8, 10, 56}`, @TheIncorrigible1 what it should generate for `{8, 9, 56}`?

Comment: @Nick I'd expect `0, 7`, `10, 55`, `57, 100`

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 I've added a check for consecutive numbers in missing which will resolve the problem with `{8, 9, 56}`

Comment: Here's another edge case:  `missing = {0, 50, 100}`

Comment: @RickHitchcock thanks for that. I've updated the code to deal with that (and I think all other) edge cases.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 Thanks to Rick pointing out the edge cases I've updated the code to resolve them (including the case where all values are missing). It just required an extra test to make sure there wasn't an output at the end where the last value was actually missing.

Answer (score 1):

There's already a good accepted answer, but this was an interesting problem.

Here is my solution, which works with edge cases:

```
def gen_ranges(start, end, missing):
  missing = sorted(missing + [start - 1, end + 1])

  for num, value in enumerate(missing):
    if value - missing[num - 1] > 1:
      yield missing[num - 1] + 1
      yield value - 1

print(list(gen_ranges(0, 100, [8, 23, 56])))          # [0, 7, 9, 22, 24, 55, 57, 100]

print(list(gen_ranges(0, 100, [5, 40, 50, 52, 93])))  # [0, 4, 6, 39, 41, 49, 51, 51, 53, 92, 94, 100]

print(list(gen_ranges(0, 100, [0, 50, 100])))         # [1, 49, 51, 99]

print(list(gen_ranges(0, 100, [0, 50, 51, 100])))     # [1, 49, 52, 99]
```